# Racism, homophobia, xenophobia etc

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any term encompassing all those "phobias"? I mean a word describing state of hatred towards all kind of minorities?

Comment: Including perhaps hatred of multi-millionaires, plutocrats, demagogues, dictators, life-insurance salesmen, cold-callers, people who fart in public etc. What is it about the three you mention that sets them apart from others who people dislike?

Comment: @ WS2: of course, a "phobia" is irrational. Some of the people in your interesting list might have good reason to be hated. :-). It's difficult to tie down the three mentioned in one group, isn't it? Racism doesn't define itself as a phobia, and "foreigners" are hardly in a minority in the world.

Comment: @WS2 Have you an authority backing up your last two examples?

Comment: I hope triskaidekaphobiacphobia is included.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It certainly plays havoc with airline seat reservations. In fact I'm told a good day to fly is Friday 13th as you avoid crowded planes and sometimes get three seats to yourself.

Comment: @WS2 I think that's triskaidekaphobia.

Comment: I can't augment my close-vote reason where I want to. It's because the question is self-contradictory, as Margana points out. And I don't even _want_ there to be a term that includes haters of mass murderers, 12-fingered people, Klono-worshippers, Manxmen ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's obvious what's meant (particularly bearing in mind the examples given in the title). If you think the question's badly-phrased and too inclusive, why not edit it to make it clearer?

Comment: @Morton 5 No it's not. Of those examples, racism and xenophobia are bigotry, whereas many people believe that the practice of homosexuality is not what man was designed for.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah, I see. Thank you for making it clear where you're coming from.

Answer (score 4):

**Bigotry**.  From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bigot), **bigot**: "a person who strongly and unfairly dislikes other people, ideas, etc. : a bigoted person; especially : a person who hates or refuses to accept the members of a particular group (such as a racial or religious group)".

Interestingly, the definition in [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bigot), "A person who is intolerant towards those holding different opinions", doesn't quite encompass that usage.  Perhaps it's cheating to choose the dictionary which agrees with you... but in this case, my personal experience suggests that Oxford hasn't caught up with the way the word's now used (at least in the UK).

**EDIT:** All right. In an attempt to counter those who are downvoting every answer because of pedantic objections to the question:

1. The word *unfairly* is a crucial part of the definition from MW. So I, as someone with mainstream views on the matter, wouldn't say that someone was "bigoted against neo-Nazis" - because in my worldview disliking neo-Nazis is not unfair.
2. It's worth noting that the definition, and (in my experience) the actual usage, don't strictly imply "minority". In my country, white people are in the majority, but it would make just as much sense to say that someone was bigoted against white people as it would to say they were bigoted against (for example) Asian people. Like all words though, it needs to be interpreted with reference to the cultural context in which it's used - and we all know that in any given society, there are some groups of people who are more commonly subject to "unfair dislike" than others.

So I agree this isn't a perfect match to what was actually asked - but I think that it, and suggestions in other answers, are getting close to what the OP was looking for.

Comment: I was going to post the same but you got there before me. In addition to *bigotry*, perhaps *prejudice* suits, if you are troubled by the OED definition.

Comment: This does not address the fact that some minorities are loathsome.

Answer (score 0):

I think ***[discrimination](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discrimination)***  may suggest hatred/dislike ***based on prejudices*** 
against specific categories of people:

> - treatment or consideration of, or making a distinction in favor of or against, a person or thing based on the group, class, or category to which that person or thing belongs rather than on individual merit:
>
>   - racial and religious intolerance and discrimination.

(dictionary.reference.com)

Comment: This does not address the fact that some minorities are loathsome.

Comment: The fact that they may be  loathsome is based on personal opinions. Discrimination encompasses all form of prejudices.

Comment: Discrimination against child-molesters?

Comment: ***Come on @EdwinAshworth!!!*** Are child molesters a 'minority'?  that  is *"a  racial, religious, political, national, or other group thought to be different from the larger group of which it is part*" or just irresponsible adults who commit  crimes against children???

Comment: From the [Guardian Comments forum](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2010/jun/11/industrial-origins-of-scottish-excess): 'Outside of leafy suburbs, "odd" minorities who like vegetables, like walking and don't like alcohol in vast quantities are easily characterised as freaks. And Glasgow University's survey seems to bear that out.' This shows that the term can be used very loosely. //

Comment: 'The fact that they may be loathsome is based on personal opinions'. Child-sacrifice cults ("a racial, religious, political, national, or other group thought to be different from the larger group of which it is part") might have argued that opponents were infringing on their religious freedom. Might still argue: 'In the early 21st century Uganda has experienced a revival of child sacrifice.' [ [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_sacrifice) ]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  - I really don't understand why you are insisting on this issue, anyway would you compare a child-molestion to  a child-sacrifice cult?  But I give up...you are just right!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Although the word "***facism***" is technically the name for a specific political movement, it is increasingly being used as a general term for intolerance toward others.

Answer (score -1):

Such persons have an , ***authoritarian personality***, which manifests itself as either a desire to dominate all those perceived to be unlike oneself, the desire to blindly follow demagogic leaders with simplistic solutions, an inability to see logical fallacies in the talking points of such leaders, or a combination of all these.

See this  enlightening free book exploring this personality disorder:  http://chasegalleryconnect.org/FNC_C/Data/Brain-Neural/Political_and_Governance_Dimensions/Bob%20Altemeyer/Authoritarians/2006%20Authoritarians%20+++++.pdf

There is also self-evalution test (the F scale) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-scale_(personality_test)

Of couse, all of this has very little to with English usage, except insofar as authoritarian leaders  tend to use English to obscure truth and promote blind faith and ignorance, rather than using the language to promote rational exploration of alternative explanations and proposed solutions.

Comment: Imagine that you use "Republicanism" in this sense to someone who does not share your political views, or who does not even live in the USA and knows nothing of US politics. Most likely it will not be understood at all, or misunderstood as meaning something completely different. If you really want to use these kinds of terms, you can use *chauvinist* or *fascist* in their colloquial senses, which are not strictly correct but at least have a precedent of such use.

Comment: '... pandering to religious zealots, neo-nazis and other such hypocrites' and '... a word describing [a] state of hatred towards all kind of minorities' does not work.

Comment: Edited answer to remove "Tepublicanism" and "pandering" paragraphs, so as to focus on the _Authoritarian Personality_. Modern American Republicanism is but one example of this phenomenon, and far from the worst example.

Comment: It is still not a good proposal. One can loathe others without wishing to impose oneself upon them. I did not object to your choice of "republicanism" so much as that all of your suggestions are tangentially relevant at best and certainly do not *mean* what the OP asks for.

Comment: Indeed, one can loathe without wishing to impose. That's why I said the Authoritarian Personality manifests itself in one or more of those ways, not necessarily all of them. The book I cited explains all these nuances, and it is as close as anyone will come to describing the type of person the OP referred to.